# Настроить Dead Letter Queue в Rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, микросервисы, spring-cloud

есть два микросервиса МС1 и МС2, которые общаются через `Rabbit MQ`. В МС2 в `application.properties` добавил настройки:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=messageConsumer;messageProduce
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messageConsumer-in-0.destination=work_company
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messageProduce-out-0.destination=work_company
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messageConsumer-in-0.group=work_company_group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messageProduce-out-0.group=work_company_group
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.messageConsumer-in-0.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
```

Сама очередь DLQ создается, но когда из МС1 отправляется сообщение в МС2 даже если оба микросервиса включены выходит ошибка:

> org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor [ERROR] 08:50:45 -
> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred
> in message handler
> [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@40867d57],
> failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[2],
> headers={contentType=application/json,
> id=5c335ebf-80fc-2d09-9823-ff1779c2cc1d, timestamp=1704952233256}]    at
> org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1196)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:332)
> at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
> at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
> at
> org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:210)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:131)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:42)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$SubscriberDecorator.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:295)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$SubscriberDecorator.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:276)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:160)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountInner.onNext(FluxRefCount.java:238)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.drain(FluxPublish.java:571)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublish.java:310)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:113)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:476)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:273)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.tryEmitMessage(FluxMessageChannel.java:86)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:75)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:332)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:302)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.sendReactiveMessage(FluxMessageChannel.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.lambda$subscribeTo$5(FluxMessageChannel.java:145)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:179)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:260)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:968)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:164)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:430)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
> at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)   at
> reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2252)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2198)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2178)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:695)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$14(RabbitAdmin.java:621)
> at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
> at
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$15(RabbitAdmin.java:620)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.lambda$onCreate$0(CompositeConnectionListener.java:38)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.forEach(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:807)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:38)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:717)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:254)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2225)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2198)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1119)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.doRabbitSend(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:250)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:231)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:180)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:145)
> at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
> ... 56 more Caused by: java.io.IOException  at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:140)     at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:136)     at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:158)
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:989)
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:47)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1167)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy163.queueDeclare(Unknown Source)     at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:856)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$initialize$16(RabbitAdmin.java:697)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.invokeAction(RabbitTemplate.java:2285)
> at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2246)
> ... 76 more Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException:
> channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406,
> reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg
> 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'work_company.work_company_group'
> in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type
> 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)     at
> com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:552)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:316)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:152)
> ... 88 more Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException:
> channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406,
> reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg
> 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'work_company.work_company_group'
> in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type
> 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)     at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:528)    at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:349)     at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:193)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:125)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:761)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$400(AMQConnection.java:48)
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:688)
> ... 1 more

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему возникает ошибка? Если настройку:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.messageConsumer-in-0.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
```

удалить все нормально. Но мне нужно использовать `DLQ` чтобы отслеживать доставку сообщение в МС2